# Thread running very slow in turtle graphics app

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, python-multithreading

I'm really not sure if I'm using threads right because I just started using them but using the threading library, I have set up a thread and linked it to a function, but for some reason that function runs very slow inside the thread compared to in the main code. I am using threading to be able to use the `time.sleep()` function at the same time as being able to input and process other things (since `time.sleep` halts the entire program for the duration that it is waiting). Sorry for long code but here it is:

```
import time
import threading
import turtle
import random

wn = turtle.Screen()
tetris = turtle.Turtle()
tetris.speed(0)
wn.tracer(0)
grid = []
tetriminos = ['t','l','j','i','s','z','o']

def time_count():
    while True:
        down()
        time.sleep(1)

t1 = threading.Thread(target=time_count)
t1.start()

#current tetrimino
class currenttetrimino():
    def __init__(self,tet,rot,centre,centreb):
        self.tet = tet
        self.rot = rot
        self.centre = centre
        self.centreb = centreb
curtet = currenttetrimino('t','1',0,0)

class square():
    def __init__(self, falling, block, color):
        self.falling = falling
        self.block = block
        self.color = color
for i in range(12):
    grid.append([])
for i in range(12):
    for j in range(25):
        grid[i].append(square(False, False, 'gray'))

def gridsquare(color):
    tetris.setheading(0)
    tetris.color(color)
    tetris.begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        tetris.forward(20)
        tetris.right(90)
    tetris.end_fill()
    tetris.color('black')

def refreshGrid():
    tetris.clear()
    for i in range(12):
        for j in range(25):
            tetris.pu()
            tetris.goto(i * 20 - 120, j * 20 - 250)
            tetris.pd()
            if grid[i][j].block == True:
                gridsquare(grid[i][j].color)
            elif grid[i][j].falling == True:
                gridsquare(grid[i][j].color)
            else:
                gridsquare('gray')

def left():
    ok = True
    for i in range(12):
        for j in range(25):
            if grid[i][j].falling == True:
                if grid[i - 1][j].block == True:
                    ok = False
    if ok == True:
        for i in range(12):
            for j in range(25):
                if grid[i][j].falling == True:
                    grid[i][j].falling = False
                    grid[i - 1][j].falling = True
                    grid[i - 1][j].color = grid[i][j].color
        curtet.centre -= 1
        refreshGrid()

def right():
    ok = True
    for i in range(12):
        for j in range(25):
            if grid[i][j].falling == True:
                if grid[i + 1][j].block == True:
                    ok = False
    if ok == True:
        for i in range(12):
            for j in range(25):
                if grid[11 - i][j].falling == True:
                    grid[11 - i][j].falling = False
                    grid[11 - i + 1][j].falling = True
                    grid[11 - i + 1][j].color = grid[11 - i][j].color
        curtet.centre += 1
        refreshGrid()

def down():
    ok = True
    for i in range(12):
        for j in range(25):
            if grid[i][j].falling == True:
                if grid[i][j - 1].block == True:
                    ok = False
    if ok == True:
        for i in range(12):
            for j in range(25):
                if grid[i][j].falling == True:
                    grid[i][j].falling = False
                    grid[i][j - 1].falling = True
                    grid[i][j - 1].color = grid[i][j].color
        curtet.centreb -= 1
        refreshGrid()
    else:
        for i in range(12):
            for j in range(25):
                if grid[i][j].falling == True:
                    grid[i][j].falling = False
                    grid[i][j].block = True
        lineClearCheck()
        refreshGrid()
        newTetrimino()

def instantDrop():
    ok = True
    for i in range(12):
        for j in range(25):
            if grid[i][j].falling == True:
                if grid[i][j - 1].block == True:
                    ok = False
    if ok == True:
        for i in range(12):
            for j in range(25):
                if grid[i][j].falling == True:
                    grid[i][j].falling = False
                    grid[i][j - 1].falling = True
                    grid[i][j - 1].color = grid[i][j].color
        curtet.centreb -= 1
        instantDrop()
    else:
        for i in range(12):
            for j in range(25):
                if grid[i][j].falling == True:
                    grid[i][j].falling = False
                    grid[i][j].block = True
        lineClearCheck()
        refreshGrid()
        newTetrimino()

def lineClearCheck():
    for i in range(24):
        ok = True
        for j in range(10):
            if grid[j][i + 1].block == False:
                ok = False
        if ok == True:
            lineClear(i)


def lineClear(y):
    y += 1
    for i in range(10):
        grid[i + 1][y].block = False
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(24):
            if j > y and grid[i + 1][j].block == True:
                grid[i + 1][j].block = False
                grid[i + 1][j - 1].block = True
                grid[i + 1][j - 1].color = grid[i + 1][j].color
    refreshGrid()
    lineClearCheck()

def rotate():
    if curtet.tet == 't':
        if curtet.rot == 1:
            if grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].block != True:
                curtet.rot += 1
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].color = grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].color
        elif curtet.rot == 2:
            if grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].block != True:
                curtet.rot += 1
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].color = grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].color
        elif curtet.rot == 3:
            if grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].block != True:
                curtet.rot += 1
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].color = grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].color
        elif curtet.rot == 4:
            if grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].block != True:
                curtet.rot = 1
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].color = grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].color
    elif curtet.tet == 'i':
        if curtet.rot == 1:
            if grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].block != True and grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].block != True and grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 2].block != True:
                curtet.rot += 1
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre - 2][curtet.centreb].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 2].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].color = grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].color
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].color = grid[curtet.centre - 2][curtet.centreb].color
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 2].color = grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].color
        elif curtet.rot == 2:
            if grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].block != True and grid[curtet.centre - 2][curtet.centreb].block != True and grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].block != True:
                curtet.rot = 1
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 2].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre - 2][curtet.centreb].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].color = grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].color
                grid[curtet.centre - 2][curtet.centreb].color = grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 2].color
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].color = grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].color
    elif curtet.tet == 'l':
        if curtet.rot == 1:
            if grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].block != True and grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].block != True and grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb - 1].block != True:
                curtet.rot += 1
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].color = grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].color
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].color = grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].color
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb - 1].color = grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].color
        elif curtet.rot == 2:
            if grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].block != True and grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].block != True and grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb - 1].block != True:
                curtet.rot += 1
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].color = grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].color
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].color = grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].color
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb - 1].color = grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb - 1].color
        elif curtet.rot == 3:
            if grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].block != True and grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].block != True and grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb + 1].block != True:
                curtet.rot += 1
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].color = grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].color
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].color = grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].color
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb + 1].color = grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb - 1].color
        elif curtet.rot == 4:
            if grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].block != True and grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].block != True and grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].block != True:
                curtet.rot = 1
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].color = grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].color
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].color = grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].color
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].color = grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb + 1].color
    elif curtet.tet == 'j':
        if curtet.rot == 1:
            if grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].block != True and grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].block != True and grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].block != True:
                curtet.rot += 1
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].color = grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].color
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].color = grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].color
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].color = grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb + 1].color
        elif curtet.rot == 2:
            if grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].block != True and grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].block != True and grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb - 1].block != True:
                curtet.rot += 1
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].color = grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].color
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].color = grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].color
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb - 1].color = grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].color
        elif curtet.rot == 3:
            if grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].block != True and grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].block != True and grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb - 1].block != True:
                curtet.rot += 1
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].color = grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].color
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].color = grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].color
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb - 1].color = grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb - 1].color
        elif curtet.rot == 4:
            if grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].block != True and grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].block != True and grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb + 1].block != True:
                curtet.rot = 1
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].color = grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].color
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].color = grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].color
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb + 1].color = grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb - 1].color
    elif curtet.tet == 'z':
        if curtet.rot == 1:
            if grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].block != True and grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].block != True:
                curtet.rot += 1
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].color = grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].color
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].color = grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb + 1].color
        elif curtet.rot == 2:
            if grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb + 1].block != True and grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].block != True:
                curtet.rot = 1
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb + 1].color = grid[curtet.centre][curtet.centreb - 1].color
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb + 1].color = grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].color
    elif curtet.tet == 's':
        if curtet.rot == 1:
            if grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb - 1].block != True and grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].block != True:
                curtet.rot += 1
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].color = grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].color
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb - 1].color = grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].color
        elif curtet.rot == 2:
            if grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].block != True and grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].block != True:
                curtet.rot = 1
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb - 1].falling = False
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].falling = True
                grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb + 1].color = grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb].color
                grid[curtet.centre - 1][curtet.centreb].color = grid[curtet.centre + 1][curtet.centreb - 1].color
    refreshGrid()


def tetrimino(a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2,d1,d2,color):
    grid[a1][a2].falling = True
    grid[b1][b2].falling = True
    grid[c1][c2].falling = True
    grid[d1][d2].falling = True
    grid[a1][a2].color = color
    grid[b1][b2].color = color
    grid[c1][c2].color = color
    grid[d1][d2].color = color

def newTetrimino():
    tet = tetriminos[random.randint(0, 6)]
    curtet.tet = tet
    curtet.rot = 1
    #'t','l','j','i','s','z','o'
    #middle top - 5, 24
    curtet.centre = 5
    curtet.centreb = 23
    if tet == 'z':
        tetrimino(5,24,5,23,4,24,6,23,'lime green')
    elif tet == 's':
        tetrimino(5,24,5,23,4,23,6,24,'red')
    elif tet == 't':
        tetrimino(5,23,4,23,6,23,5,24,'dark magenta')
    elif tet == 'l':
        tetrimino(5,23,4,23,6,23,6,24,'dark orange')
    elif tet == 'j':
        tetrimino(5,23,4,23,6,23,4,24,'blue')
    elif tet == 'i':
        tetrimino(4,24,5,24,6,24,7,24,'cyan')
        curtet.centre = 6
        curtet.centreb = 24
    elif tet == 'o':
        tetrimino(5,24,6,24,5,23,6,23,'gold')
    refreshGrid()

newTetrimino()
for i in range(25):
    grid[0][i].block = True
    grid[0][i].color = 'black'
for i in range(25):
    grid[11][i].block = True
    grid[11][i].color = 'black'
for i in range(12):
    grid[i][0].block = True
    grid[i][0].color = 'black'

refreshGrid()
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(left,'a')
wn.onkeypress(right,'d')
wn.onkeypress(down,'s')
wn.onkeypress(rotate,'w')
wn.onkeypress(instantDrop,'space')
wn.mainloop()
```

What is supposed to happen: every 1 second it runs the `down()` function

What happens: it runs it very slow for some reason (you can remove the thread and run it and press 's' to see what it is supposed to be like).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this type of question belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). [so] is for code that doesn't work as expected, not unexpected performance.

Comment: The code in your question stops almost immediately with a `NameError: name 'down' is not defined` on the call to it inside `time_count()`, so you haven't posted a [mre].

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: It looks like you want to use thread so to speed up your computing code. The thing is threads are not meant for that in Python. This will not be faster because of the *Global Interpreter Lock* (GIL). In fact, this will likely be slower due to overheads like context switches. The main way to speed up your code with CPython is to use the *multiprocessing* package which create processes. Note that multiprocessing also introduces expensive overheads. Parallelism is a mess in CPython. The GIL removal is planned since a long time but it is still there since more than a decade...

Comment: Another approach to speed up your code is to use Numpy. Numpy will make your code simpler and faster if you use Numpy (vectorized) functions. It internally use a much more more efficient approach than list of lists (it makes use of SIMD instructions and native types). Note that this approach requires to rewrite entirely your code.